# Community Bot Logic: Bumping Question to Homepage

Tags: bug

Often times I see questions bumped to the homepage by the Community Bot and don't bat an eyelash, but the question [SQL Server Database Mirroring : strange client application behavior upon failover](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22671/sql-server-database-mirroring-strange-client-application-behavior-upon-failove), made me wonder if the underlying logic needs a tweak?  The reason specified by the bot:

> bumped to the homepage by Community♦ 9 hours ago
>
> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has
>   marked it active **so that they can be reviewed.**

This question in particular was asked in August 2012 and only received its first answer back in February.  The question is, in my opinion, beyond the point where any suggestions made can be verified if they solve the OP's problem or not (e.g. the question is almost 4 years old, very specific to a user's environment, and also asked by a user that has logged minimal activity).

I'm not saying this question should be removed automatically (as it doesn't meet the [abandoned question criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)), but instead of promoting the question to the homepage for review, shouldn't the bot be flagging this question for review in one of the established [review queues](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review) without promoting it, or alternatively, just leave it alone?

Here's a similar, though more recently asked question fitting the same pattern: [SQL Server Management Studio 2016](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142769/sql-server-management-studio-2016)

Comment: Flagging the question for review as [what category](http://dba.stackexchange.com/review) exactly?

Comment: Also, I disagree that a very old question is "*obviously* beyond the point where any suggestions made can be verified if they solve the OP's problem or not". It's merely *likely* so. And questions here are more than just their respective authors' problems anyway. This is a Knowledge Base site to a much greater extent than it is a Solve My Problem one. An answer, even if it's hard or impossible to verify by the OP, may be verified by others encountering the same problem, and voted on. That specific question has received some recognition as a useful question, so can its answers be.

Comment: @AndriyM - I've updated my question accordingly.  Thanks for the feedback!